# AJAX and Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery, rss

I want to dynamically parse RSS feeds.
I have a select list and I would like to send a value (id) to the controller with ajax.
and after, I want to parse RSS feeds corresponding to the id

My Controller home.php :

```
function view($type = NULL)
{
    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('flux_model');

    if ($type == "ajax") {// load ajax view                 
        $flux = $this->flux_model->get_one_flux($this->input->post('id'));// ajax id
        $flux2 = $flux[0]->url_flux;
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($flux2, NULL, TRUE);
        //my foreach
        $this->load->view('messages_list', $data);
        }
    else{ // load the default view      
        $nb_min = 0;
        $nb_max = 7;
        $nombre = mt_rand($nb_min,$nb_max);
        $flux = $this->flux_model->get_one_flux($nombre);
        $flux2 = $flux[0]->url_flux;
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($flux2, NULL, TRUE);
        //my foreach
        $this->load->view('default', $data);
        }
}
```

Ajax script :

```
    $("#myform1 #rss").change(function(){  
    var msg = $('#myform1 #rss').val();

    $.post("<?= site_url('home/view/ajax') ?>", {id: msg}, function() {
        $('#main').load("<?= site_url('home/view/ajax') ?>");
        $('##myform1 #country').val('');
    });
```

});

view default works, I parse an RSS feed randomly
but with the ajax view, I have this error:
Message: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity ""

it looks like I do not get the id?! ajax problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is with

```
$.post("<?= site_url('home/view/ajax') ?>" [etc.]
```

Because many sites' configurations will prevent cross-site Ajax requests (See [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)), your $.post will be prevented. Instead, try something like:

```
$.post("controller/method/parameters" [etc.]
```

**Example**:

In your JavaScript:

```
$.post("ajax/myajax/myparam",{},function(data) { alert(data); });
```

And in your controllers/ajax.php file:

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function myAjax(parameter='')
    {
        /**
         * Load models, or whatever. Then echo the results, so that
         * $.post gets its "data" var.
         */
    }

}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just replace :

```
  $.post("<?= site_url('home/view/ajax') ?>", {id: msg}, function() {
  $('#main').load("<?= site_url('home/view/ajax') ?>");
  $('##myform1 #country').val('');
  });
```

by

```
  $.post('<?= site_url('home/view/ajax') ?>', options,     function(data) {
  $('#content').html(data);
 })
```